# Explode sin perder delimitador

Tags: php

Tengo un string, lo quiero dividir con el delimitador de número, pero no quiero que el número en sí sea un elemento del array

Tengo este código que obviamente no funciona, ya que no se cómo hacerlo

```html
$string = "CARTON2BS3CT1APT";
$array = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $string );

Array
(
[0] => CARTON
[1] => 2
[2] => BS
[3] => 3
[4] => CT
[5] => 1
[6] => APT
)
```

En este caso en concreto me gustaría poder conseguir esto:

```html
array {

    [0] => "CARTON",
    [1] => "2BS",
    [2] => "3CT",
    [3] => "1APT"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscar donde quieres separar la cadena y agregar un *"separador"* personalizado (`ej: [sep]`)
- Al resultado, separarlo usando el *"separador"* que has agregado en la cadena

#### Ejemplo:

```
$string = "CARTON2BS3CT1APT";
$array = preg_split("/\[sep\]/", preg_replace("/([0-9])/", '[sep]$1', $string));
var_export($array);

// Resultado
array (
  0 => 'CARTON',
  1 => '2BS',
  2 => '3CT',
  3 => '1APT',
)
```

---

**PD:** En mi ejemplo no uso tu patrón porque con el mismo no se consigue resultado esperado. Independientemente del patrón, la idea es la misma.